# Showing (embedded) closed captions in MP4

Tags: html, flash, video, mp4, mediaelement.js

I am using mediaelement.js to place a video onto the web page.  For those unfamiliar with it, it is a video player element that takes in a single source video and displays in various formats (HTML5 or flash) based upon browser capabilities

The mp4 that I am using has the captions embedded into itself.  Is there a way with HTML5 or mediaelement.js to display these captions.  I know that I can pull an external track:

```
<track kind="subtitles" src="subtitles.srt" srclang="en" />
```

but since it is embedded I would prefer to use those.  This is what my code looks like:

```
<video width="640" height="360" style="width:100%; height: 100%;" src="myvid.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="video1"  controls="controls">
    <source src="myvid.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <object width="640" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flashmediaelement.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="flashmediaelement.swf" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&amp;file=myvid.mp4 />
        <!-- Image fall back for non-HTML5 browser with JavaScript turned off and no Flash player installed -->
        No video playback capabilities
    </object>
</video>
```

Comment: when you play your video in MEJS, doesn't it display the (embedded) captions?

Comment: No, but maybe I am not initializing it properly.